# How to remove 2 double quote when export from excel to txt

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Im trying to export excel column to txt with vba.
but there are some extra double quote in each text.
How to remove the extra double quote.?

```
Dim field As String
Dim table As String
Dim t As Integer
Dim f As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim myFile As String
Dim xStr As String

myFile = "D:\table.txt"

With Sheets("Sheet1")
Open myFile For Output As #1
table = """name"": """ & .Range("I2") & """," & Chr(10)
Write #1, table

lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For f = 2 To lastrow
    field = """names"": [" & Chr(10) & """" & .Range("B" & f) & """" & Chr(10) & _
             "],"
'Display 3 Lines of Text in a Messagebox
  Write #1, field
'    Cells(i, 1).Value = 100
Next f

Close #1
End With
```

i expect the output 
"name": "customer",

but output is :
"""name"": ""customer"",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Print` and not `Write` (which adds the `"`)

Comment: And actualy i trying to extract some table with their column, name as table and names as column, dou you know any reference how to loop some table on same sheet?

Comment: If you're having a different problem then try posting another question explainig the difficulty.